# C, Preprocessor Macro, and GCC Error: "expected expression before..."

Tags: c, makefile, compiler-errors, c-preprocessor

I found libipfix, an IPFIX collector written in C, long ago.  The original authors have vanished, but the code is still available on github.  I'm assuming that if it is up there, it has worked for other people.

When I try to run the Makefile for a specific subprogram (example_collector_db), I'm getting an "expected expression before..." message from GCC which doesn't make a lot of sense to me.  Here's the Makefile, albeit heavily abridged:

```
CC = gcc
CCOPT = -Wall -g
INCLS = -I. -I.. -I../lib -I../libmisc
DEFS = -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
CFLAGS = $(CCOPT) $(INCLS) $(DEFS)
CPPFLAGS =
LDFLAGS =
LIBS =    -L../lib -L../libmisc -lipfix -lmisc

example_collector_db: example_collector_db.o Makefile
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ example_collector_db.o $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)
```

But here's what happens when I run the make:

```
root@myLinux:/home/me/libipfix_110209/examples# make example_collector_db
gcc -Wall -g -I. -I.. -I../lib -I../libmisc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -c example_collector_db.c
In file included from ../libmisc/misc.h:39:0,
                 from example_collector_db.c:54:
../libmisc/hashtable.h:6:1: error: expected expression before 'struct'
 struct hashtable;
 ^
Makefile:72: recipe for target 'example_collector_db.o' failed
make: *** [example_collector_db.o] Error 1
root@myLinux:/home/me/libipfix_110209/examples#
```

Hmm.  It looks like the code is trying to use a "hashtable.h" header file.  When I take a look, I see this:

```
  1  /* Copyright (C) 2002 Christopher Clark <firstname.lastname@cl.cam.ac.uk> */
  2  
  3  #ifndef __HASHTABLE_CWC22_H__
  4  #define __HASHTABLE_CWC22_H__
  5  
  6  struct hashtable;
  7  
  X  ...more code here...   
  X
166  #endif /* __HASHTABLE_CWC22_H__ */
```

So GCC appears to be complaining about Line 6, which I believe to be prototype (?) or signature (?) of a valid struct somewhere else in the code.  But I can't help wonder if GCC is really complaining about Line 4... shouldn't that #define statement have another token, eg:

```
  4  #define __HASHTABLE_CWC22_H__   12345   // or something...?
```

At first glance, I'm tempted to assume that Line 4 is the problem and this code can't work until a third token is added.  But the coder who wrote this is much more advanced than I am.  And how could this project live on github for nearly fifteen years if the code had such a simple mistake?

Forgive the "sanity check" nature of this post...  I'm hoping there's something more advanced at play here which my intermediate-level experience is overlooking...

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like the issue with the file including this one.

Comment: "I'm assuming that if it is up there, it has worked for other people" is not a valid assumption.  The only thing that it being on github surely means is that somebody pushed it there.  Not that it ever worked, not that they included the totality of their changes.  FWIW.

Comment: This looks a bit as if the file included _before_ this header from the c file has some problems at the end such as a missing semicolon.

Comment: There's a lot going on in that repository, including automatic generation of header files (including the one which is probably creating the problem). However, there is no problem with the header guard you see in hashtable.h except for its name; that is the entirely bog-standard way of doing a header guard. (It defines the symbol to have an empty replacement list, which is still a definition.) All names starting with two underscores are reserved for the compiler/standard library, but that particular name is probably safe in practice even if it is explicitly disallowed.